# How to animate two lines at once with Matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation class in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am currently trying to animate my numerical algorithms for the 3-body-problem. It all works fine when I animate a single trajectory, but I am not able to do the same for two or three at the same time. I kind of understand the problem, I keep overwriting my plot1 with plot2 then plot2 with plot1 and so on. This leads to some weired flickering. Sadly I failed to solve it. I think I need to reduce to a single *animation.FuncAnimation()* and combine *animate1()* with *animate2()* and *init1()* with *init2()*.
I would appreciate any kind of help.
Here is a  minimum, reproducible example that shows the problem.

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np  
  

fig = plt.figure()  
axis = plt.axes(xlim =(-50, 50),  
                ylim =(-50, 50))  
  
line1, = axis.plot([], [], 'r', animated=True)
line2, = axis.plot([], [], 'b', animated=True)
  

def init1():  
    line1.set_data([], [])  
    return line1,  

def init2():  
    line2.set_data([], [])  
    return line2,

 
xdata1, ydata1 = [], [] 
xdata2, ydata2 = [], []
  

def animate1(i):  
    t = 0.1 * i  
      
    x = t * np.sin(t)  
    y = t * np.cos(t)  
       
    xdata1.append(x)  
    ydata1.append(y)  
    line1.set_data(xdata1, ydata1)  
      
    return line1,

def animate2(i):  
    t = 0.1 * i  
    x = t * np.cos(t)  
    y = (-t) * np.sin(t)  
    xdata2.append(x)  
    ydata2.append(y)  
    line2.set_data(xdata2, ydata2)    
    return line2,
       
anim1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate1,  
                            init_func = init1,  
                            frames = 500, 
                            interval = 20,  
                            blit = True)

anim2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate2,  
                            init_func = init2,  
                            frames = 500, 
                            interval = 20,  
                            blit = True)
```

Comment: why not jut update both lines at the same time in one single `update` function? Don't forget to return both lines

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly as you said and I also mentioned, I just didn't manage to get it right so far. I had difficulties with the correct output when combining them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Only thing that still bothers me, is that the last frame adds a line from the end-point to the starting-point.

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np  
  
fig = plt.figure()  
axis = plt.axes(xlim =(-50, 50),  
                ylim =(-50, 50))  
  
line1, = axis.plot([], [], 'r', animated=True)
line2, = axis.plot([], [], 'b', animated=True)
  
def init():  
    line1.set_data([], [])  
    line2.set_data([], [])  
    return line1, line2,

xdata1, ydata1 = [], [] 
xdata2, ydata2 = [], []
  
def animate(i):  
    t1 = 0.1 * i   
    x1 = t1 * np.sin(t1)  
    y1 = t1 * np.cos(t1)    
    xdata1.append(x1)  
    ydata1.append(y1)  
    line1.set_data(xdata1, ydata1)  
    t2 = 0.1 * i  
    x2 = t2 * np.cos(t2)  
    y2 = (-t2) * np.sin(t2)  
    xdata2.append(x2)  
    ydata2.append(y2)  
    line2.set_data(xdata2, ydata2)
    return line1, line2

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  
                            init_func = init,  
                            frames = 500, 
                            interval = 20,  
                            blit = True)
```